# How can I find the order of elimination in Josephus Problem in C?

Tags: c, josephus

The Josephus can be solved with the following algorithm:

> ```
> int josephus(int n, int k)
> {
>   if (n == 1)
>     return 1;
>   else
>     return (josephus(n - 1, k) + k-1) % n + 1;
> }
> ```

However, I would also like to know who was the i-th person killed in the game. For example, with n=10, k=2, the 1st person to get killed is the 2nd. How can I get this answer? Is there anyway I can find it using the algorithm above?

Comment: Provide an [mre] in your question, probably off-topic here. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and of your debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)). Then use the debugger to understand the behavior of your program. Read about [*call stacks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) - often limited to a megabyte or a few of them.

Comment: Read also the wikipage of [Josephus Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem). Thanks for mentioning it here, I never heard of it. You first have to do some math before coding more. Maybe you'll need [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

Answer (score 0):

### An O(m*lg(km)) algorithm

`n` people in a ring, numbered from `0` to `n-1` clockwise.
Start from person with number `0`, every `m`-th is executed, the following program give number of the `k`-th killed person. `k` start from `0`.

```py
def solve(n,m,k):
    if m==1: return k
    i = (k+1)*m-1
    while i>=n:
        i = (m*(i-n))//(m-1)
    return i
```

#### Explanation

I use `//` to denote `floor divison`.

let's say everyone will additionally count off from `0`, who reports `m-1` is the `0`-th killed person. who reports `2m-1` is the `1`-th killed person and so on.

Say somebody reports `i`. His last reports is `j`.
When he reports `j`, there are `j//m` dead, `n-(j//m)` alive.

So `i = (n - (j//m)) + j` -> `j-j//m = i-n`

Suppose `j = am + b; 0<=b<m-1; a,b is int`, notice here `b!=m-1` because he won't die.

Then `a(m-1) + b = (i-n)` . Using bezout's lemma and extended euclidean
algorithm, we got `a=-c; b=(i-n)+c*(m-1); with any int c`. And `b` has only one solution in interval `[0,m-1)`. So `b = ((i-n)+c*(m-1)) %(m-1)`, which equals to `(i-n)%(m-1)`. After that, you can calculate `j=(i-n) + (i-n)//(m-1) = (m*(i-n))//(m-1)`.

By this recurrence relation, you can calculate any `k`-th killed person.

Time complexity `O(m*lg(mk))`.

### An O(n*lg(n)) simulation algorithm

If `m` is pretty large, you can use some Balance Tree to implement an O(n*lg(n)) algorithm.

```py
# pip install sortedcontainers
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
def simulate(n, m):
    # all index start from 0
    people = SortedList(range(n))
    idx = 0
    while len(people)>0:
        idx = (idx+m-1)%len(people)
        yield people.pop(idx) # yield executed people number in order
    return
```